# Navigation Drawer ic_drawer and logo not together on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat

I'm trying to use NavigationDrawer with appcompat and actionbar. My NavDrawer is working, both by sliding from the left or by touching the actionbar.

At [the navigation drawer sample app](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) the `home icon` at the Action Bar is shown within the same "container" as the 3-stripes-drawable that indicates there's a side menu. But at my app the `home icon` is shown outside this "container"... I'm uploading pictures to explain better what is happening. Also, the `home icon` is appearing much bigger than at google's sample app, despite being the same size (96x96 at xhdpi). The ic_drawer drawable is the same in both apps.

I don't want to use the same drawable as the app launcher icon.

On both screenshots, I am touching the actionbar to open the nav drawer (see the highlighted square):
[image: here is how it looks now]
[image: here is how I want it]

my manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

my style:

```
<resources>
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="background">@color/black</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item>
</style>
<style name="TitleTextStyle"
    parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

my MainActivity's onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Are you using app compat 21?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes, com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3

Answer (score 1):

The navigation drawer sample app displays the old ActionBarDrawerToggle used with api<21. This example should be updated.

With the new appcompat 21, the pattern is changed.

The Action Bar follows the material design guidelines and uses a Toolbar.
As you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

```
The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is 
    discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.
```

If you would like an application icon, you can use the method `setLogo()`.

You should read this [official post](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

Pay attention to [android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html). This class is deprecated.
You should use the [new class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) which works with the new Toolbar.

Comment: Thanks. If I use `setLogo()` it shows the logo just like at the first image (outside of the clickable square). I still want to keep the old logo+title pattern...

Comment: so what is the solution?